# Open data versus public data

Tags: discussion

I put up a question, not intending it to be provocative for the group, asking people's understanding of the difference between [open data and public data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/is-there-a-difference-between-open-data-and-public-data).

I think the difference is material and important, specifically around the ownership, use and distribution of the data/results of public data.

It was suggested by @Joe, that I put a note here for discussion and pose a few questions. Not sure of the normal way that meta sites are handled as compared to normal sites.

- Should there be a broadening of the remit of Open Data SE to include public data explicitly?